# QT/QML Business logic separated from the UI

Tags: qt, qml, qt-signals

I'm trying to put the business logic in `Main.qml` and the UI in `MainForm.ui.qml` but I can't connect both by widget id.

MainForm.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {
   id: page
   header: TabBar { ... }
   StackLayout {
      id: stack
      Pane {
         Flow {
            TextField {
               id: theText
            }
            property alias sendBtn: sendBtn
            Button {
               id: sendBtn
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480
   title: qsTr("Hello World")
   MainForm {
      anchors.fill: parent
      sendBtn {
         onClicked: backend.sendTextToServer( theText.text )
      }
   }
}
```

Qt Creator says : `Invalid property name "sendBtn" (M16)`

Running failed with the following messages:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/Main.qml:12 Cannot assign to non-existent property "sendBtn"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put `property alias sendBtn: sendBtn` inside Pane is interpreted as being a Pane property so you can not access it that way, it is correct to place it in the context of Page.

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {
   id: page
   property alias sendBtn: sendBtn
   property alias theText: theText
   header: TabBar { ... }
   StackLayout {
      id: stack
      Pane {
         Flow {
            TextField {
               id: theText
            }

            Button {
               id: sendBtn
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```